# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to+\infty}(e^n-\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+a^2}}),$ where $a>0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I need method to find this limits :

$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\mathrm{e}^{n} -
\sum_{m = 0}^{n}\frac{1}{\,\sqrt{\,{m^{2} + a^{2}}\,}\,}\right)$, where $a >0 $.
What about if replace $\mathrm{e}^{n}$ with $\ln\left(n\right)$ ?.

Please give me ideas.

Comment: What is $m$? Is it constant?

Comment: it is meant to be k

Comment: And the radical? is it $\sqrt{k^2+a^2}$?

Comment: Here is how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You can add braces to extend the square root sign: \$\sqrt{m^2+a^2}\$ becomes $\sqrt{m^2+a^2}$.

Comment: There's no need to be sorry. Please show your work if you have any to [ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @tobyMak I don't have anyideas

Comment: Since the answer to this has been given (it's $\infty$) why not start a new question with $\ln n$ in place of $e^n$?

Answer (score 0):

For $a<m$,
$$\frac1{m-a}<\frac1{\sqrt{m^2+a^2}}$$
So,
$$e^n-\sum_{m= 0}^n\frac1{\sqrt{m^2+a^2}}>e^n-\sum_{m>a}^n\frac1{m-a}>e^n-\ln (n-a)-1\to\infty$$

Comment: What about if $\ln n$ not $e^n$

Answer (score 0):

The integral representation you gave is wrong. Notice that
$$
\sum_{m=0}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+a^2}}\leq \frac{1}{a}+\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+a^2}}\leq \frac{1}{a}+\sum_{m=1}^n \frac m m  \leq \frac 1 a + n
$$
So
$$e^n -\sum_{m=0}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+a^2}}\geq e^n - \frac 1 a -n $$
That means?

Comment: What about if replace $e^n$ with $\ln(n)$

Comment: @Rozeflowers then the story gets different of course...I think we get a finite number

Comment: Can you see plz , is $\lim=+{\infty}$???

Comment: So which method evaluate lim when replace $e^n$ with $\ln n$

Comment: I don't know, but I think looking at digamma function might help, at least the methods used for that function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function

Comment: Thank you very much sir

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{\expo{n} -
\sum_{m = 0}^{n}{1 \over \root{m^{2} + a^{2}}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over \verts{a}} + \lim_{n \to \infty}
\pars{\expo{n} - \sum_{m = 1}^{n}{1 \over \root{m^{2} + a^{2}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over \verts{a}} + \lim_{n \to \infty}
\bracks{\expo{n} -
\sum_{m = 1}^{n}\pars{{1 \over \root{m^{2} + a^{2}}} - {1 \over m}} -
H_{n}}
\end{align}
where $\ds{H_{z}}$ is the *Harmonic Number*.

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{\expo{n} -
\sum_{m = 0}^{n}{1 \over \root{m^{2} + a^{2}}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over \verts{a}} +
a^{2}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over m^{2} + a^{2} + m\root{m^{2} + a^{2}}}\ +\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\underbrace{\bracks{\expo{n} - H_{n}}}
_{\ds{\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\Huge\to}\,\,\,\Huge\infty}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much sir @FelixMarin , can you give me hints if $\ln n$ not $e^n$

Comment: @Rozeflowers $\displaystyle\qquad\ln\left(n\right) - H_{n} \sim\color{red}{ -\gamma} - {1 \over 2n} + {1 \over 12n^{2}}$ as $\displaystyle n \to \infty$. See [Harmonic Number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Thanks , but  why for example : $\sum_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt(m^2+a^2)}$ equivalent $H_n$

Comment: @Rozeflowers $\color{red}{No}$. $\displaystyle H_{n} = 
\sum_{m = 1}^{n}{1 \over m}$.

Comment: OK , how I use $H_n$ here !?